# How to get output of command line to python

Tags: python

I run windows command line programm from python, the command line programm return strings, for example: I run that line

```
subprocess.call("RPiHubCMDTool.exe dev", shell=True)
```

and I see in cmd window the output `dev0 FT2232H RPi HUB Module A 136241  A , 
dev1 FT2232H RPi HUB Module B 136242  B`. I whant to work in python with that output. How to bring it from cmd window to python? Could you provide an example?

Answer (score 1):

to get the output you can use

```
output=subprocess.check_output(["echo", "Hello World!"])
print output
# Hello World!
```

Comment: what is the output type (str,int ...) ?

Comment: @MAXK it will be string

Comment: @MAXK how are you comparing the output. please edit your question and post it there

Comment: i see the id_code (output) is equal to 0x10cd

Comment: @MAXK  can you edit your question its dificult to understand . do you see same output when you excute the command in command prompt

Comment: my code is `if id_code == '0x10cd' : print 'WORK ' else: print 'BASSA'` so it print BASSA

Comment: @nataraj Сундар I see in python when i print the id_code that it eque to 0x10cd but when i run if conparation it return fall value ..

Answer (score 0):

How about write the result to a file and read this file in python?

```
subprocess.call("RPiHubCMDTool.exe dev > result.txt", shell=True)
f = open('result.txt', 'r')
# do something with f
```